The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception en API Core .NET 6
Tengo una api, que al probarla en mi localhost funciona bien, pero en el servidor de donde lo llamo en el publicado, me sale el error:
The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception
EL codigo en el controller siguiente:
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("obtienerespuesta")]
public async Task<List<ResponsePymeModels>> InboundTransfersItauPyme(string api_key, string AccountLink, string AccountNumber, string urlbanco, string BookingDate)
        {
                var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
                Configuere(serviceCollection);
                var servicios = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
                var httpClientFactory = servicios.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>();
                var client = httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
                client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(230);
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-api-key", api_key);
                var json = new JObject(
                     new JProperty("RequestData",
                         new JObject(
                             new JProperty("AccountCredential",
                                 new JObject(
                                     new JProperty("AccountLink", AccountLink)
                                 )
                             ),
                             new JProperty("AccountNumber", AccountNumber),
                             new JProperty("BookingDate", BookingDate),
                             new JProperty("Currency", "CLP")
                                 )
                             )
                 );
                var postData = new StringContent(json.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                var request = await client.PostAsync(urlbanco, postData);//aki se cae
                var response = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

  }
 private static void Configuere(ServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient();
        
    }

En el inner exception dice:

System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Authentication
failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert:
'HandshakeFailure'.\r\n ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception
(0x80090326): Mensaje recibido inesperado, o bien su formato es
incorrecto.\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at
System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter
adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean
isApm)\r\n   at
System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.EstablishSslConnectionAsync(SslClientAuthenticationOptions
sslOptions, HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Stream stream,
CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Se cae en la linea PostAsync. Me gustaría si alguien pudiera ayudarme o indicar como darle solucióon. Desde ya, gracias.

¿Puedes mostrar el "Inner exception"?

Hola @PeterM, eso me sale en el Inner exception

No sé nada sobre TLS, pero cuando google "remote party sent a TLS alert: 'HandshakeFailure'", recibo muchos resultados que sugieren que el problema  está en la versión del protocolo TLS y no en el código.  Por ejemplo aquí

Estan bien los certificados en todos lados??? aparte de eso, sabias que .net tiene librerias que automaticamente transforman una clase en un JSON, sin necesidad de hacer todo eso que haces ahi???

@gbianchi, gracias por responder. De que forma debo chequear los certificados?. Al pasarlo a JSON, se solucionaria el problema?. Será porque uso httpClientFactory , y debo habilitar algo en el programs?

Lo de los certificados lo saben los que aramaron la red.. no se como se testean, yo por lo menos no lo hago... no se a que te referis con pasarlo a JSON.. lo que te decia es que no tenes porque construir el JSON a mano, .net lo puede hacer por vos si provees la clase con el formato de JSON que queres....  lo ultimo ni idea....

Yo tuve una experiencia similar a tu caso con el mismo error comunicándonos con Mutual TLS 1.3 resultando el mismo error del HandShake que presentas, según investigué HttpClient usa ciertos algoritmos criptográficos dependiendo de la versión TLS que usas y obtiene los CipherSuit de la maquina, en comparación con OpenSSL, CURL, PostMan, Chrome que tiene su propio baúl criptográfico independiente de la maquina, por lo que debes asegurar que tu Maquina o Servidor tenga el CipherSuite que necesita para pasar el "Client Hello", en mi caso nuestro servidor se usaba en Windows Server 2012 y no tiene el CipherSuite TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256 que requería para comunicarnos.
Soluciones:

Puedes agregar ese CipherSuite pero es complicado y puede corromper la maquina si no sabes lo que haces.
Usar librerías externas, o (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest que ya es absoluta pero tiene su propio baúl criptográfico y de hecho es la solución que opté, nos funcionó. Espero le sea de ayuda.

